# Throw-away prototyping Vs Iterative development

Tags: iteration, prototyping

Can Someone distinguish *Throw-away prototyping* and *Iterative development*.

Answer (score 2):

Both methods of prototyping are used when there's some aspect of the system that you don't entirely understand. However, the key difference is the lifecycle methodology that you use. With evolutionary prototyping, you typically understand some aspects of the system and aren't sure about others. In throwaway prototyping, you have a general lack of understanding that you need to complete before you can build a production-ready system.

Note that there are lots of kinds of throwaway prototyping, and neither are limited to the entire system. For example, using paper or whiteboard sketches of a user interface can be considered throwaway prototyping. Yes, you might go through several iterations and throw away a previous design, but you also won't use the final prototype in the system (it's not physically possible, for one).

If you're interested in general software engineering topics and the breadth of SE, I'd highly suggest picking up the Sommerville book that I quote. It's really good for covering the breadth of topics. If you're more interested in process models and methodologies and how you can apply them to various projects, I'd recommend the McConnell book - it has an entire chapter devoted to evolutionary prototyping and another chapter devoted to throwaway prototyping.

I also took a quick glance at the Wikipedia article on software prototyping. Some parts of it are a little weird (at least on my quick read), but there doesn't appear to be anything that I downright disagree with. Some of it is a little focused on one particular aspect, but it's not factually wrong that I see. I prefer the definitions below, but it might be an interesting read on various types of prototyping.